# "Error: $apply already in progress" when using FireBaseAuthClient with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm trying to record the logged in user in an AngularJS scope, but getting an error when the page first loads up.

Clicking "Login" seems to work, but then logout bails with the same "$apply already in progress" error.

I'm expecting I've just misunderstood how `$apply` works, can anybody help?

**Update**:

It works seamlessly if I wrap just the `if (user)` part in `$apply()` as follows.

```
var auth = new FirebaseAuthClient(ref, function(error, user) {
    if (user) {
        $scope.$apply(function(){ $scope.user = user; });
        console.log(user);
    } else if (error) {
        // I can't vouch for this, haven't tested it
        $scope.$apply(function(){ $scope.user = null; });
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        $scope.user = null;
        console.log("logged out");
    }
});
```

**Original code**:

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['firebase']);
```

controller.js:

```
app.controller('Login', ['$scope', 'angularFire',
function($scope, angularFire) {
    $scope.loginstatus = 'logged out';

    var ref = new Firebase("https://app.firebaseio.com/");
    var auth = new FirebaseAuthClient(ref, function(error, user) {
        if (user) {
            $scope.$apply(function(){ $scope.loginstatus = 'logged in'; });
        } else if (error) {
            $scope.$apply(function(){ $scope.loginstatus = 'error'; });
            alert("Login error: " + error);
        } else {
            $scope.$apply(function(){ $scope.loginstatus = 'logged out'; });
        }
    });

    $scope.login = function(provider, args) {
        auth.login(provider, args);
    }

    $scope.logout = function() {
        auth.logout();
    }
}]);
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>App</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js">
    <script type="text/javascript" src='https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase-auth-client.js'></script></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angularFire.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="Login">
    <p>Login status: {{loginstatus}}</p>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Login</h1>
      <p>
        <button ng-hide="user" ng-click="login('twitter')" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Login</button>
        <button ng-show="user" ng-click="logout()" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Logout</button>
      </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$apply` is only needed when you're outside of the context of Angular (like a setTimeout, setInterval, or non-Angular XHR callback).

Since FireBaseAuthClient is a tool written with Angular in mind and injected into your controller, it's likely that the callbacks are already wrapped in `$scope.$apply`.  You can fix your code by removing `$scope.$apply`, so just:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://app.firebaseio.com/");
var auth = new FirebaseAuthClient(ref, function(error, user) {
    if (user) {
        $scope.loginstatus = 'logged in';
    } else if (error) {
        $scope.loginstatus = 'error';
        alert("Login error: " + error);
    } else {
        $scope.loginstatus = 'logged out';
    }
});
```

Comment: Cheers for the reply but that doesn't work. That's what I had to begin with. The callback works cos I can see console output if I shove it in there, but `$scope` doesn't get updated. This is symptomatic of not being "inside angular", hence why I started fiddling with `$apply()`.

Comment: It works if I wrap just the "logged in" logic and leave the logout logic as you have above. See my original question for an update.

Comment: That being said, you may need to use $apply in a ``promise``. Just an FYI.